# cannot open include file 'winresrc.h'

Tags: c++, sdk

Visual Studio 19, code (MFC) can be compiled on the machine if Platform Toolset is set to VS 2010 or VS 2017 but not if set to VS 2019 (V142). Which SDK do I need and where do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio Installer and make sure if you have installed MFC, ATL and some Windows SDK. Check in the "Individual components". Note that MFC is not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings dialog of the project I set the SDK-Version to 'newest' (installed) and this fixed the problem.

I erroneously assumed that the SDK-Version was automatically set to the correct version when I changed the Platform Toolset.